# Show specific Div inside ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a bunch of cards using ngFor with user's information. There is a button inside the card that will display travel information for that specific user.

I created a div with the initial state `display: none`. I thought about using `ngStyle` to bind the `display: block` property upon click, but the problem is that all the divs are getting displayed and not only the specific one I need.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

**html**

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
   <i class="material-icons" (click)="showBox()">access_alarm</i>

   <div class="travel-info" [ngStyle]="{'display': boxDisplay == true ? 'block' : 'none'}" >
      <app-travel-info ></app-travel-info>
   </div>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
boxDisplay = false;

showBox() {
    this.boxDisplay = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @ViewChildren. I give you this example:

***Your HTML:***

```
<div class="student-container" *ngFor="let s of students; let i = index">
  <span>Name: {{s.name}} - Index: {{i}}</span>
  <div class="student-box" #boxes>
    <span>Hey! I'm opened.</span>
    <span>My Secret Number is: {{s.secretNumber}}</span>
  </div>
  <button (click)="toggleBox(i)">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

***Your Component:***

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren("boxes") private boxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  students = [
    { name: "Peter", secretNumber: "88" },
    { name: "Laura", secretNumber: "45" },
    { name: "Paul", secretNumber: "13" }
  ];

  toggleBox(index) {
    let nativeElement = this.boxes.toArray()[index].nativeElement;
    nativeElement.style.display =
      nativeElement.style.display === "none" || !nativeElement.style.display
        ? "block"
        : "none";
  }
}
```

***Your CSS:***

```
.student-container {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.student-box {
  display: none;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zwqoxp583x

Comment: Hey @Nicolas M thank you very much! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @iconio I guess you can also add a boolean attr to your "student object", something like "isOpen" and in your toggleBox method use the index to search in your students array for your student and set the isOpen variable to true or false depending the case (maybe something like student.isOpen = !student.isOpen). Then you can avoid using the ViewChildren if your rendered list is too long, and just use *ngIf with that student.isOpen variable, and remove the #boxes template ref var. Hope It helps!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you only have one variable that is set for all of them.

You will want to refactor showBox to be something like this.

**TS**

```
this.boxDisplay = this.students.map(s => false);

showBox(index) {
  this.boxDisplay[index] = true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
   <i class="material-icons" (click)="showBox(i)">access_alarm</i>

   <div class="travel-info" [ngStyle]="{'display': boxDisplay[i] == true ? 'block' : 'none'}" >
      <app-travel-info ></app-travel-info>
   </div>
</div>
```

If it were me I would use ngIf instead of the ngStyle.

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
   <i class="material-icons" (click)="showBox(i)">access_alarm</i>

   <div class="travel-info" *ngIf="boxDisplay[i]" >
      <app-travel-info ></app-travel-info>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a property display with each elements of the students array and then enable/disable based on the index,

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index">
   <i class="material-icons" (click)="showBox(student)">access_alarm</i>
   <div class="travel-info" [ngStyle]"{'display': student.boxDisplay == true ? 'block' : 'none'}" >
      <app-travel-info ></app-travel-info>
   </div>
</div>


showBox(student:any) {
    student.boxDisplay = true;
}
```